# Glass Mapper 5 lazy loading

Tags: glass-mapper

We migrated to `Sitecore 10.1` and `Glass Mapper` is upgraded to `5.8.177.0 from 4.3.4.197`.

I noticed the mapping was not working.

I changed the code from

```
var centreHours = glassContext.GetItem<TradingHoursModel>(Rendering.DataSourceItem.Fields["Centre Hours"].Value);
```

to

```
 var centreHours = _mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<TradingHoursModel>(Rendering.DataSourceItem.Fields["Centre Hours"].Value);
```

The model was null and then I added `x.LazyDisabled()`

```
var centreHours =  _mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<TradingHoursModel>(Rendering.DataSourceItem.Fields["Centre Hours Datasource"].Value, x => x.LazyDisabled());
```

It started working after `x.LazyDisabled()`. Do I need to pass `x.LazyDisabled()` in all the `.GetItem` method?

Since this is a data source item, I also tried the following code but it didn't work and the model was null.

```
_mvcContext.GetDataSourceItem<TradingHoursModel>(new GetKnownOptions { Lazy = Glass.Mapper.LazyLoading.Disabled});
```

Comment: Did you try like this?
IMvcContext mvcContext = new MvcContext();
var mapItem= mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<IMap>(DataSourceItem);

Comment: @GauravAgarwal yeah this is what I tried but didn;t work _mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<TradingHoursModel>(Rendering.DataSourceItem.Fields["Centre Hours"].Value);  Then, I passed x.LazyDisabled() and it starts working

Comment: Is there any security applied on the datasource item? I had a similar issue and reported this issue https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/440

Comment: @Jeroen No there is not security applied in my scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have written a generic class for all the `MVCContent Sitecore service methods`. If you don't want to pass `x.LazyDisabled()` in all the `.GetItem` methods, you can modify your code as below:

```
  public T GetItem<T>(GetItemOptions options) where T : class
    {
        options.Lazy = Glass.Mapper.LazyLoading.Disabled;
        return _mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<T>(options);
    }
```

Other options with `LazyLoading`:

```
public enum LazyLoading
{
    Enabled = 0,
    Disabled = 10,
    OnlyReferenced = 20
}
```

**Update:**

Refer to below sample code to create a `generic class`:

```
 public class RenderingRepository : IRenderingRepository
 {
    private readonly IMvcContext _mvcContext;

    public RenderingRepository(IMvcContext mvcContext)
    {
        _mvcContext = mvcContext;
    }
    public T GetItem<T>(GetItemOptions options) where T : class
    {
        options.Lazy = Glass.Mapper.LazyLoading.Disabled;
        return _mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<T>(options);
    }
}
```

Register it into your DI:

```
 serviceCollection.AddTransient<IRenderingRepository, RenderingRepository>();
```

Now using `Controller Constructor DI`, you can use this method in your controller Action Result:

```
public class SampleController : SitecoreController
{
    private readonly IRenderingRepository _renderingRepository;
    public Sample(IRenderingRepository renderingRepository)
    {
        _renderingRepository = renderingRepository;
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_renderingRepository.MethodName());
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I have not written any generic class. I am following the Sitecore Habitat example (https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src). Can you guide me on the generic class. Are there any examples? Thanks

Comment: I have only created a class to register all new Glass services . I have used the following example (https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/29431/glass-mapper-upgrade-to-5-8-177-0-getdatasource-is-no-longer-working-after-glas)

Comment: I have updated the code snippet for the generic class. Hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks alot. It’s working