# Implementing Lazy on ContextItem

Tags: glass-mapper

We are upgrading GlassMapper to V5 and installed Glass.Mapper.Sc.90. I am doing all the changes mentioned in http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/documentation/Upgrade-ToV5.html link one by one. Now, i am working on Lazy.

I have disabled Lazy on Model and trying to implement on services when a model is requested. So far the below is working fine
 `_mvcContext.**GetDataSourceItem**<ITest>(x => x.LazyDisabled());`

But when trying the below, i am getting an error.

`_mvcContext.**GetContextItem**<IPageBase>(x => x.LazyDisabled());`
When I mouse hover on **x => x.LazyDisabled()**, I am seeing **Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'GetKnownOptions' because it is not a delegate type**

also the webpage errors out with below stack trace.

***Model depth check failed. Model graph too large, enable lazy loading. Type requested: Test.Models.ISitecoreItemTest.Models.ISitecoreItem
Test.Models.ISitecoreItem
Test.Models.ISitecoreItem
Test.Models.ISitecoreItem
Test.Models.ISitecoreItem
Test.Models.ISitecoreItem
Test.Models.ISitecoreItem
Test.Models.Common.IPageBase***

What should I do here? Thoughts?

my `GlassMapperScCustom.cs` looks like below

`public static IDependencyResolver CreateResolver(){
var config = new Glass.Mapper.Sc.Config();

```
        //Needed to avoid Model-too - deep exception
        config.OnDemandMappingEnabled = true;
        config.Cache.AlwaysOn = true;

        //config.EnableLazyLoadingForCachableModels = true;             // Only for V4. Deprecated in V5
        var dependencyResolver = new DependencyResolver(config);
        // add any changes to the standard resolver here
        dependencyResolver.ObjectConstructionFactory.Remove<ItemVersionCountByRevisionTask>();
        //dependencyResolver.ObjectConstructionFactory.Remove<ModelDepthCheck>(); // **This is not working.**
        
        return dependencyResolver;
    }`
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have given the same answer here. You can refer. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30410/glass-mapper-5-lazy-loading/30420#30420

Comment: @HimmatSinghDulawat: Thanks for writing. I already saw the above post. It clearly explains the generic class where we enable/disable Lazy for all the GetItem. But I don't want lazy to get disabled/enabled for all GetItem. So I am trying to write it individually on each call.

Comment: also added GlassMapperScCustom.cs if there is something i am missing.

Comment: Try this if you dont want ofr all GetItem:  var dataSource = _mvcContext.GetDataSourceItem<IPageBase>(new GetKnownOptions { Lazy = Glass.Mapper.LazyLoading.Disabled});

Comment: Thanks @HimmatSinghDulawat i see that My solution has t4 templates in TDS, where the Cacheable= true is set for all templates. We have to disable it and everything started working fine like using new GetKnownOptions { Lazy = Glass.Mapper.LazyLoading.Disabled} on ContextItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the *GetContextItem* method, you'll see it accepts *GetKnownOptions* as a parameter now.

Then you can just do something like that:

```
_mvcContext.**GetContextItem**<IPageBase>(new GetKnownOptions{Lazy = LazyLoading.Disabled});
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for writing. I tried your code sample above but it didn't work. Although the above code is accepted and compiles clean, I still have the same error on the same line (can confirm this by having a breakpoint)

Comment: also added GlassMapperScCustom.cs if there is something i am missing.

Comment: Thanks @MiguelMinoldo,  I see that My solution has t4 templates in TDS, where the Cacheable= true is set for all templates. We have to disable/remove it and everything started working fine after using new GetKnownOptions { Lazy = Glass.Mapper.LazyLoading.Disabled} on ContextItem